# App Engine: What is the lifetime of the app-level registry in webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I wonder if the registry is kept between backend restarts. Is it a persistent shared storage, or memory only, or something in between?

Comment: Exactly what registry are you talking about?

Comment: @Daniel: webapp2.get_app().registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry you referenced is stored in the `webapp2.WSGIApplication` instance and therefore is available for the life of that [Frontend Instance](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances).

webapp2 also offers a [registry for each Request](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Request.registry).

Reference:

- http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/app.html#registry